# Configure application access policy with microsoft teams error exception calling "GetRemoteNewCsOnlineSession"

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, powershell-5.1

Am new to powershell and using [this procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/cloud-communication-online-meeting-application-access-policy) to set application policy with microsoft team
The above is necessary when creating online meetings as per [this procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#examples)
but whenever i run

```
Grant-CsApplicationAccessPolicy -PolicyName Test-policy -Identity "appid"
```

Am getting an error

```
Exception calling "GetSteppablePipeline" with "1" argument(s): 
"Exception calling "GetRemoteNewCsOnlineSession" with
 "1" argument(s): "Run either Connect-MicrosoftTeams or new-csonlinesession before running cmdlets."
```

I have already Connected using admin credentials by using

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
```

I have powershell 5.1 on my device.

What am i missing or how do i resolve the error above.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please check which module your using GA or public preview module,if you have installed both,please do uninstall GA and try to set the policy
2. Update teams module , close and reopen the powershell and try to assign the policy

[Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/teams-powershell-install)

Please do let me know if above steps works for you

Comment: How do i check which module whether GA or public preview module?

Comment: Get-InstalledModule
   [[-Name] <String[]>]
   [-MinimumVersion <String>]
   [-RequiredVersion <String>]
   [-MaximumVersion <String>]
   [-AllVersions]
   [-AllowPrerelease]
   [<CommonParameters>]  [reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/get-installedmodule?view=powershell-7.1#:~:text=The%20Get%2DInstalledModule%20cmdlet%20gets,Get%2DModule%20%2DListAvailable%20command.)